# Bash command to get directory file permissions for every file within

Tags: bash

Is it possible to write a bash command that would write to a file a (key, value) structure that would represent every file within given directory and its corresponding file permissions as octal number (i.e. 664)? I know this command returns an octal value:

```
stat -c '%a' /path/to/file/
```

but I don't know how to combine it with walking through a directory and writing it out to a file. What might be useful is also this command that creates my_md5.txt file with key, value like structure of hash codes...

```
find /path/to/file/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > /tmp/my_md5.txt
```

but I don't know how to combine the two bits of code to do what I want.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at GNU find's `-printf` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like that?

```
find -type f -exec stat -c "%n: %a" {} \; | cut -b 3- > output.txt
```

**explanation**

- find all files in working directory
- print name and permissions
- ignore first two characters from filename "./"
- write to outputfile

Comment: Amazing! That's exactly what I had in mind. Thank you

Comment: With GNU find: `find -type f -printf "%f: %m\n" > output.txt`